# How do I write result like this

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, and I want to write a query to calculate column **Result** that compares each column in first table with the second table.

```
DECLARE @result TABLE (A INT, B INT, C INT, D INT, E INT, F INT, G INT)
INSERT INTO @result ( A, B, C, D, E, F, G) 
VALUES ( 2, 14,19,20,35,41,15)

DECLARE @bet TABLE (A INT, B INT, C INT, D INT, E INT, F INT)
INSERT INTO @bet ( A, B, C, D, E, F) 
VALUES( 2, 14,19,20,35,41 ),
      ( 5, 14,15,20,33,46 ),
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a lot of answer on SO on how to create a delimited list in SQL Server, and I suspect that is the problem you are having, not the comparison.

Comment: expected output: that is yellow column I marked

Comment: And how do your tables relate?

Comment: i want to write a query show value in black table that matched value in blue table below, and show up

Comment: Your result table has column G that is not presented in your bet table. With what column G should be compared?

Comment: please, don't care G column. Simple, I need a sql statement show result like G yellow column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ','+CAST(X as varchar(4)) [*]
    FROM (VALUES (A),(B),(C),(D),(E),(F)) T(X)
    WHERE X IN (
        SELECT X
        FROM @result
        UNPIVOT (X FOR Y IN (A,B,C,D,E,F,G)) P
    )
    ORDER BY X FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM @bet
```

**Result:**

```
Result
-------------------
2,14,19,20,35,41
14,15,20
NULL
```

Comment: wait, you can not compare one by one column, the value of column A (black table) can exist column B( blue table)

Comment: tks so much. ^^ that's supprise